# Linear Regression: Row (as observation) vs Variables

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

**R-newbie here**...

So I want to conduct a regression analysis on a dataset that summarizes vehicle collisions from 2012 - 2016. Thing is, every row represents the occurrence of an accident. The tables looks like this:

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMt9h.png) snapshot

Basically, there are thousands of rows for 2012, 2013 etc with variables assigned such as month, time of day, hour, vehicle year, driver age etc...

So if I wanted plot Accidents Vs. Hour, how would that be done.

Sorry if this is an extremely stupid question.. trying to teach myself...

THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We really don't want to type in your data to answer your question. Instead,  please use `dput(YourData, 20)` to make a printable sample of your data,  then paste that into your question so that we can transfer it into R.  You might also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think that you need to begin with `table(MyData$C_HOUR)`

Answer (score 1):

The base function for ploting is plot(). But I think you are looking for a histogram like this (example with iris):

```
> data(iris)
> #iris
> 
> hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
```

[image]

Use ?hist() for help.